# about script tags inside form tags

Tags: javascript, html

i have added a script tag in side a select tag which creates options dynamically. The function works fine but the W3C validator gives me 4 errors regarding this syntax. It will be helpful if you guys could find me a solution for this problem.

These are the **2 errors** that repeat 2 times.

**1.** document type does not allow element "script" here

**2.**  year_option(); end tag for "select" which is not finished

Comment: To debug your markup, it would help if you posted your markup.

Comment: I'm glad you use the W3C validator. It would be wise to listen to what it says "document type does not allow element `script` here". So move that `<script>` block out of your `<select>` tag. It should go in the `<head>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) the only tags that `<select>` can have are `<option>` and `<optgroup>` tags
the validator is complaining because `<script>` is not one of those things -- the browser is doing its best to take your invalid markup and turn it into something valid, so despite the fact that it works, that's why you get the error, if you're actually putting `<script>` tags inside of a `<select>`

2) your script tags should be at the bottom of your page, and instead of using `document.write` to put option tags there, use DOM methods to add options to the select element after the fact

```
<select name="select-box"></select>
<!-- ...rest of page... -->
<script src="external-script.js"></script>

/* contents of external-script.js */
var select_box = document.querySelector("select[name=select-box]"),
    bob_opt  = document.createElement("option"),
    doug_opt = document.createElement("option");

bob_opt.value  = "Bob";
doug_opt.value = "Doug";
bob_opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bob"));
doug_opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Doug"));

select_box.appendChild(bob_opt);
select_box.appendChild(doug_opt);
```

There are faster and neater, or more-elaborate or more flexible ways of doing this, but this is closer to the "right way" than something like:

```
<select>
    <script>document.write("<option value=\"" + i + "\">one</option>");</script>
</select>
```

Or whatever you might currently have there.
JS is not meant to be templated like that, without using/writing a templating library for that purpose.

Comment: `<script>` tags don't have to be placed in the `<head>` or before end of `<body>` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28364607

Comment: @DanielSokolowski of course they don't have to be only in the `<head>` or at the end of the `<body>`...  ...you can put them all over your page, and inside of any element which expects flow content. That, however, is a ***bad*** idea, despite its technical viability.  If you are writing an application which 100% requires libraries/frameworks to function (and content can't be shown, otherwise), they should probably go in the head; otherwise, they should be deferred until initial content is visible and interactive, to improve perceived speed).

Comment: I think we agree that it depends on the situation :). It used to be a bad idea but now a days we have `async` and `defer` and browsers now pre-scan/pre-load pages prior to parsing. I used to religiously put things in the `<head>` but now I simply do what makes sense from a design perspective; I prefer my widgets to be self contained rather then depend on some globally defined `domready` entry point.

Comment: @DanielSokolowski it's not about having them in the head, so much as not having `<body><main><section><article><header><script src="...">...`. That right there is a maintenance nightmare. Writing a promise-enabled script loader (or using JSPM / Duo / Webpack / Browserify) or simply a decent Gulp / Broccoli / etc build-step is preferable. But depending on your demographic, async script attributes can't be leaned upon (in my case, I've never had that option for employers). If scripts are declared at the bottom of `<body>` you show prerendered content, first and still don't care about "ready".

Answer (score 0):

1) Script tags should be located in head, or perhaps elsewhere in the document, but not inside select tags

2) Looks like you are missing a  tag, or perhaps its having problems finding it because of the first error.

Comment: `<script>` elements do not always need to be located in the head of the document, depending on when the script is needed.

Comment: I didn't say they had to, I said should. As you can read I also stated that they can be elsewhere, but not inside select tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `JavaScript` out side the `select` tag, and you can append `option` tags later, when `select` tag is rendered on the page, after page load using `$(document).ready`.

You can standardize your code by placing JavaScript in separate file, there you can do like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Your code to init all things,
//e.g. load options in select box etc..
//so It will be easy later to maintain the code, all init code will go here
});
```

Or if you are not using jquery, you can use below code

```
function your_function(){
//your init code will go here
}
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onLoad = your_function;
```

that's it, place your code in `your_function()`

Comment: Assuming that he is using jQuery. It will be a bit more complicated without that.

Comment: no, @fredrik you can do it withouth jquery using `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onLoad = your_function();", and you can place all your code in your_function().

Comment: This way you can place all your JavaScript code in a separate file, and in organized way.

Comment: Yes, but your example is jQuery based - and you don't know if hes using that. All I said was that it would be a bit more complicated -which you have just shown...

Comment: it is not complicated @fredrik, it is only one line of code, is it hard/complicated for you? :D

Comment: I did not say that it would be complicated - just more so than the jQuery way.

Comment: @fredrik, yes you are 100% right, using frameworks make it is for programmer to deliver on time, and many other benefits, I agree.