# Input type file not sending as php email attachment

Tags: php, html, input

I am trying to send a html `<input type="file"` document as an attachment in php email, using php mail().

The email sends, but the attachment is not in the email.

**Here is the relevant HTML:**

```
<td> <label class="custom-file-upload">
<input type="file" onchange="fileNameC()" tabindex="28" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" required/>
<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload profile</label>
</td>
<td><p id="fileNameT"></p></td>
     <td><button id="remove" style="visibility: hidden" onclick="remove();">Remove</button></td>
```

In the HTML I am using a javascript function `fileNameC()`, here is the code for the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function (){
           var file = document.getElementById('fileupload').value;
           if(file){
               f = file.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');
               if(confirm("Do you want to select " + f) == true){
                document.getElementById("fileNameT").innerHTML = "File " + f + " attached!";
               document.getElementById('remove').style.visibility='visible';fileNameC
               document.getElementById('remove').style.visibility='inline';
               document.getElementById('remove').innerHTML = "Remove :" + f;  
               }else{
                        document.getElementById('remove').style.visibility='hidden';
               document.getElementById('remove').innerHTML = ""; 
               }

           }

       }

</script>
```

and a `remove()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function remove(){
           document.getElementById('fileupload').value = "";
            document.getElementById('remove').style.visibility='hidden';
            document.getElementById("fileNameT").innerHTML = " ";
       }
   </script>
```

**The form's action is executed in php:**

```
$fileName = $_FILES["fileupload"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["fileupload"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["fileupload"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["fileupload"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["fileupload"]["name"]);

//read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
$handle = fopen($fileName, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $fileSize);
fclose($handle);
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$boundary = md5("random"); // define boundary with a md5 hashed value 

//header 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; // Defining the MIME version 
$headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; // Sender Email 
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."\r\n"; // Email addrress to reach back 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n"; // Defining Content-Type 
$headers .= "boundary = $boundary\r\n"; //Defining the Boundary 

//attachment 
$body .= "--$boundary\r\n"; 
$body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
$body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
$body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
$body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\r\n\r\n";  
$body .= $encoded_content; // Attaching the encoded file with email 

$to_email =  'myemail@mysite.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$body =  "Email written content goes here - This part works";

//attachment 
$body .= "--$boundary\r\n"; 
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
$body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
$body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\r\n\r\n";  
$body .= $encoded_content; // Attaching the encoded file with email 

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= "From: Identykidz Info <" . $from_email . ">\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

 //send email
 mail($to_email, "$subject", $body, $headers);
```

**I have tried the following to sort my issue,**

1) I have checked the error_log and got the following:

> fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in /path/to/my/file/myfile.php on line 11
>
> fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/to/my/file/myfile.php on line 12
>
> fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/to/my/file/myfile.php on line 13

2) I then ran a test to echo the `$fileName` to view the file name brought over to php, nothing displays.

3) I have searched and tried other php code to create the attachment.I had not luck.

It seems like none of the file details are received by the php code. I cannot understand the reason, I have double checked everything and cannot find the issue.

Please help.

**EDIT:

Form code:**

```
      <form name="register" id='register' enctype="multipart/form-data" action='PersonsEmail.php' method='post' autocomplete="off"  accept-charset='UTF-8' onsubmit="displayLoader()">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-50">
        <center><h3 style="font-family: Verdana; color: #1e73be;"> Person Report Form</h3></center>
        <h4 style="font-family: Verdana;">Pererson's detail</h4>
        <label for="fname" id="lblmpname">Person's Name and Surname:</label>
                   <input type='text' name='mpName' id='mpName' tabindex="1" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Person's Name and Surname" class="txt idnr" required maxlength="150" />

        <label for="pname" id="lblmpage">Age:</label>
       <input type='text' name='mpAge' id='mpAge' tabindex="2" class="txt" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Age of person" required maxlength="50" /><br/>
       <label>Gender</label>
       <select tabindex="3" name='mpgender' required>
            <option value="select" selected="selected" disabled>Please select gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>

<label>Province</label>
       <select tabindex="5" name="mpprovince" required>
            <option value="select" selected="selected" disabled>Please select province</option>
            <option value="Limpopo">Limpopo</option>
            <option value="Gauteng">Gauteng</option>
            <option value="North West">North West</option>
            <option value="Northern Cape">Northern Cape</option>
            <option value="Western Cape">Western Cape</option>
            <option value="East Cape">East Cape</option>
            <option value="Mpumalanga">Mpumalanga</option>
            <option value="Kwazulu Natal">Kwazulu Natal</option>
            <option value="Freestate">Freestate</option>
</select>
      <br>
      <hr>
     <h4 style="font-family: Verdana;">Person's description:</h4>
      <label>Hair colour:</label>
<p><input tabindex="13" placeholder="Hair colour of person" type="text" id="haircolour" name="haircolour"></p>
      <label>Hair lenght / style:</label>
<p><input tabindex="14" placeholder="Hair lenght or style of person" type="text" id="hairlenght" name="hairlenght"></p>
<label>Eye colour:</label>
<p><input tabindex="15" placeholder="Eye colour of person" type="text" id="eyecolour" name="eyecolour"></p>
<label>Height:</label>
<p><input tabindex="16" placeholder="Height of person" type="text" id="height" name="height"></p>
<label>Weight / Build:</label>
<p><input tabindex="17" placeholder="Weight or build of the person" type="text" id="weight" name="weight"></p>
<label>Distinctive marks, tattoos or any characteristics:</label>
<p><input tabindex="18" placeholder="Distinctive marks, tattoos or any characteristics of person" type="text" id="marks" name="marks"></p>
<label for="adr" id="lblalternative">Any alternative description or information?</label>
        <textarea name='alternative' id='alternative' tabindex="19" cols="60" rows="4" tabindex="6" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Optional" required="required" maxlength="124" /></textarea><br/>
      <hr>
       <label for="email" id="lblfamilycontactemail">Contact Person's Email</label>
       <input type='text' name='familycontactemail' id='familycontactemail' spellcheck="false" tabindex="27" class="txt"  placeholder="Email address of the family contact person." pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required maxlength="50" /><br/>

        <br>
        <hr>
        <h4 style="font-family: Verdana;">Identity profile / Photo</h4>

 <table>
 <tr>
     <td> <label id="fileload" class="custom-file-upload">
<input type="file" onchange="fileNameC()" tabindex="28" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" required/>
<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload IdentyKidz profile or recent photo</label>
</td>
     <td><p id="fileNameT"></p></td>
     <td><button id="remove" style="visibility: hidden" onclick="remove();">Remove</button></td>
 </tr>



 </table>
   <br>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function remove(){
           document.getElementById('fileupload').value = "";
            document.getElementById('remove').style.visibility='hidden';
            document.getElementById("fileNameT").innerHTML = " ";
       }
   </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
       function fileCheck(){
           var file = document.getElementById('fileupload').value;
           if(file){
             //Do nothing, because         document.getElementById("fileNameT").innerHTML =  was changed by function fileNameC
           }
           else{
               alert('No File Uploaded');

           }
       }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
       function fileNameC(){
           var file = document.getElementById('fileupload').value;
           if(file){
               f = file.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');
               if(confirm("Do you want to select " + f) == true){
                document.getElementById("fileNameT").innerHTML = "File " + f + " attached!";
                       document.getElementById('remove').style.visibility='visible';
                   document.getElementById('remove').style.visibility='inline';
               document.getElementById('remove').innerHTML = "Remove :" + f;  
               }else{
                        document.getElementById('remove').style.visibility='hidden';
               document.getElementById('remove').innerHTML = ""; 
               }

           }

       }

</script>

        <br>
        <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" id="submit" onclick="fileCheck();" tabindex="30" class="btn">
  </form>
```

Comment: no idea about this, starting debuging from `print_r($_FILES);` check what are u getting

Comment: If `$fileName` is empty, then the problem has nothing to do with your email code.

Comment: or may be you are not using `multipart` in your `<form>`

Comment: @devpro. Many thanks for the advise. I did remove all code but not the `$_FILES` code and the used `print_r($_FILES);`. I got a result `Array ( ) `.

Comment: then add `multipart/form-data` in `<form>`

Comment: @PatrickQ. Thanks I thought so, but one never know where you might be missing something. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @devpro. Thanks. I added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>`, same result.

Comment: from where you submitting your form? using ajax or simple submission?

Comment: @devpro. Normal Html form with submit button

Comment: add your <form> code also in your question

Comment: From the description of your error_log, looks like the file is not being posted over to the server-side correctly. The issue is most likely with your <form> and submit button/input. Do show the HTML of the entire <form>.

Comment: @CharlesWashington Can you explain the purpose of the `fileNameC()` function?

Comment: @devpro. `<form>` code added

Comment: @PatrickQ. I added the fileNameC() to check when the user loads a file, to confirm with javascript `confirm` with user if they loaded the correct file. If not it will show a button which gives the user the option to delete the file and upload another.

Comment: Why are you including `script` tags inside your form? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354608/about-script-tags-inside-form-tags

Comment: @UdoE.Thank you. I will edit my code

Comment: @devpro after I included `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form, I ran another test to echo the name in PHP. I can now view the name, and the email sent, but still no attachment.

Comment: @devpro. The error log now shows the following: `
fopen(_4KP7444.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/my/file/myfile.php on line 11`

Comment: attachment always create an issue with email body. i suggest you to use attachment link in your message body something like "Download File" instead of attachment